# Submit a form generated by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

The login form on my site is shown using an overlay/modal with jquery-modal (http://kylefox.ca/jquery-modal/examples/)

I'm using ajax + php to validate the form. If validation passes, the form should be submitted.

I can halt the submit for validation (using return false), and the validation itself is working fine. But I don't know how to *submit* the form

I have tried many naive variations: return true, $theform.submit(), $("body").unbind("#myloginform") and more.. but so far no luck

```
$("body").on("submit", "#myloginform", function() {

    $theform = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: "login_check.php",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        timeout: 9000,
        data: $theform.serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) {
                if (data.status == "ok") {
                    alert("success! now the form can be submitted");
                    // SUBMIT THE FORM (instead of the alert)
                } else {
                    $("body #loginstatus").html(data.status);
                }
            } else {
                alert("Error bla bla.");
            }
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert("Error (ajax) bla bla.");
        }
    });

    return false;

});
```

Comment: Although I didn't find any reference saying that submit won't work with delegated events. I'd try to do a direct even handling if possible and test. Something like this `$("#myloginform").on("submit",  function() `

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I can't directly refer to the form like that, as it is created/launched by javascript (I guess)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To submit the FORM, you can call js native submit method:

`document.getElementById('myloginform').submit();`

See variants:

```
$('#myloginform')[0].submit();
$('#myloginform').get(0).submit();
```

An other way would be to set `context` option of ajax to `this`:

```
$.ajax({
     context: this,
     ...,
});
```

And then in success callback, submit FORM using:

```
this.submit();
```

EDIT: i see you are already using a variable reference, so in your case, you can use too:

```
$theform[0].submit();
```

All these snippets won't trigger jQuery submit handler, avoiding a circular reference error.

Comment: I'm curious, won't this methods trigger the event and then jQuery will process it?

Comment: Brilliant. I think I will use the last one: $theform[0].submit(); (a bit more elegant no?). Could not get the context to work. Thanks

Comment: @acontell What do you mean by `then jQuery will process it`? Calling native submit method doesn't trigger jQuery submit handler bound on the FORM

Comment: don't take it personal, I didn't know this methods and I was asking for an explanation...

Comment: @mowgli The most 'elegant' way is to use the context option imho.

Comment: @acontell I didn't take it 'personaly', really not ;)

Comment: glad to know :) it's a nice approach, I'll use it in the future

Comment: I wonder why $theform[0].submit(); can be used, but not $theform.submit();

Comment: @mowgli Because using `$theform.submit();` will retrigger same jQuery handler. Now it could be possible before recalling it to unbind this event, e.g: `$theform.off('submit').submit();`

Comment: @A.Wolff Ok hm. Tried the bit you posted just now, and that did not work. Oh well.. I'll stick to $theform[0].submit();

Comment: @mowgli Not sure how do you tested it, but works here, using a timeout to simulate a async request: http://jsfiddle.net/qt1vqxe0/  But anyway,  the best approach would be to call native js submit method just as you do

Comment: @A.Wolff You are not using dynamically created form on that like I do.. and $("body").on("submit", "#myloginform", etc. I think thats why.. The scope is complicated ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff ;) I wish I understood how to treat js generated content better.. instead of using $("body").on("submit", "#myloginform", function() { etc.. But maybe thats the only way

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
var checkValid = false;
$("body").on("submit", "#myloginform", function () {
    $theform = $(this);

    if (!checkValid) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "login_check.php",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            timeout: 9000,
            data: $theform.serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    if (data.status == "ok") {
                        alert("success! now the form can be submitted");
                        // Everything is OK
                        checkValid = true;
                        $theform.submit();// Next time, no validation process, just natural send of the form.
                    } else {
                        $("body #loginstatus").html(data.status);
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("Error bla bla.");
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert("Error (ajax) bla bla.");
            }
        });

        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: this does not answer the question in any way

Comment: it does, try it and you'll see

Comment: it clearly does not answer the question.. The ajax part should not be skipped, why suggest that? And you suggest that the form be submitted more than once?

Comment: First time you try to submit, it validates. When the ajax finishes, it sets the variable to true and submits. The event triggers again but this time the variable is true, skips the validation and submits the form

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using jQuery, I would suggest that you check out the jQuery submit function

http://api.jquery.com/submit/